# Horizontal scrolling in Android Chrome with JavaScript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile

I have just created a little testcode, you can find it here

http://paloula.de/test/width_002.html

It works fine under Chrome/Windows but not if you simulate a mobile phone under Chrome/Windows (e.g. Galaxy S5) or under Android mobile phone with Chrome: The page is scrolling left, but maximum of scrollLeft is not reached.

Is it the css? Is it the meta-tag? The calculation seems to be correct.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Full Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/> 
  <style>  
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

} 
HTML {
  display: block;
  position: relative;  
  height:100%;
} 
BODY {
  display: block;
  position: relative; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  /* overflow-y: scroll; */
}   
  </style>
 
 </head>
 <body id="body"> 
  <div style="background-color: #FF0000; display: block; position: relative; width: 1700px; height: 50px;">
    <div style="background-color: #0000FF; display: block; position: absolute; width: 50px; height: 50px; right: 0"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #FF00FF; display: block; position: absolute; width: 50px; height: 50px; left: 0"></div>
  </div>  

  <script>
    var scrollWidth = document.documentElement.scrollWidth;
    var clientWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var offsetWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
    console.log(scrollWidth);
    console.log(clientWidth);
    console.log(offsetWidth);   
    
    var maxScrollLeft = scrollWidth - clientWidth;
    console.log("maxScrollLeft " + maxScrollLeft)
    
    setTimeout(function() { 
       window.scrollTo(maxScrollLeft, 0);
    }, 1); 

    setTimeout(function() {  
       window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 500);          
  </script>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add minimum-scale=1 to the meta/viewport tag

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0,  minimum-scale=1"/>
```